# Enjoy You Shall

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay

> My prefix you do with trash,
>
> My infix duplicated.
>
> Without half of my infix the suffix gets lazy,
>
> And the word you definitely enjoy!

Comment: I have found a typo in the riddle, edited... @practiced_liar is right anyway... Congrats!

Comment: @GentlePurpleRain just out of curiosity, why did you edit a bunch of Riley riddles (this was the last one) within a few minutes of each other?

Comment: He was changing my titles to remove the numbering. Thanks to @GentlePurpleRain

Comment: Ah OK that's cool. I was really confused, especially because all of the edits were flying in so quickly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is it:

> RIDDLE

My prefix you do with trash,

> You get RID of trash.

My infix duplicated.

> Double the D for DD.

With half of my infix the suffix gets lazy,

> Remove the duplicate D to get the suffix IDLE

And the word you definitely enjoy!

> And we definitely enjoy a good RIDDLE!

Comment: You're just sooooooooooooooooooooo quick...